# Customizing python package directory layout with setup.py

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, distutils, python-packaging

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
└── python/
    └── generated/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── a.py
        └── lib/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── b.py
```

What does my `setup.py` need to look like in order to create a dist with a directory layout like:

```
src/
└── python/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    └── lib/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── b.py
```

The goal is to simply eliminate the `generated` folder.  I've tried endless variations with `package_dir` and can't get anything produced other than the original directory structure.

Comment: Do you see any error or it basically does not output anything? Can you please highlight what happens with the execution of setup?

Comment: Please list all the combinations you have tried for `package_dir` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Many were experiments in the moment that were immediately discarded after failure.  The records are lost.  User `sinoroc` provided a great solution if you are interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this specific case, for this specific project directory structure, the `setup.py` script should be placed in the `src` directory and should look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
    
import setuptools
    
setuptools.setup(
    name='Thing',
    version='1.2.3',
    packages=[
        'python',
        'python.lib',
    ],
    package_dir={
        'python': 'python/generated',
    },
)
```

Note the `package_dir` setting. It instructs `setuptools` to get the code for the `python` package from the directory `python/generated`. In the *built* distributions you will then find the right directory structure.

Comment: Placing the `setup.py` inside the `src` directory was not an option for me.  But I was about to get the desired result with the same principle: `package_dir: { 'src.python': 'src/python/generated' }` and adjusting the `packages`! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad it helps. Note that you could do `package_dir: { 'whatever_package_name_you_like': 'src/python/generated' }`, and adjust the `packages` argument accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, here is my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, shutil
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

class BuildPyCommand(build_py):
  """Custom build command."""

  def run(self):
    shutil.rmtree('src.tmp', ignore_errors=True)
    os.mkdir('src.tmp')
    shutil.copytree('src/python/generated', 'src.tmp/python')
    build_py.run(self)

setup(cmdclass={ 'build_py': BuildPyCommand },
      name='Blabla',
      version='1.0',
      description='best desc ever',
      author='Me',
      packages=['python', 'python.lib'],
      package_dir={'': 'src.tmp'},
      setup_requires=['wheel']
     )
```

And you can generate your distribution with:

```
python setup.py build bdist_wheel
```

The idea is perform a two steps build:

- I generate a valid source structure
- I build this temporary structure

And I deliver it in a wheel because it doesn't require future users to understand my trick. If you give it a try with a source distribution, you will notice that you need to publish the generated files as data (not difficult, but troublesome, and, I guess you will want to hide your tricks from your users).

But, I think that there is a design flaw in your process. The file `src/python/generated/__init__.py`, assumed to be a module `<something>.generated` eventually becomes your `<something>.python`, which is troublesome. It would be much simpler and more robust to generate a valid Python structure: `src/generated/python/__init__.py`. The setup.py would become trivial and your generator wouldn't be more complex.

Comment: Thanks! The insight into the generated layout is helpful!