# Setup.py Install Package under a different top level name

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I have a project such as:

```
myproject
    setup.py
    -myproject
       -package1
       -package2
```

I am using a setup.py as:

```
NAME='myproject'
setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests',)),
    package_data={NAME: ['VERSION']},
    install_requires=require(),
    extras_require={},
    include_package_data=True)
```

When I install (`pip install -e .`) this I can access the packages as `import myproject.package1`. However, I want to change this so I instead import it as `import mynewname.package1`. In the example above when changing `NAME=mynewname` and then installing, the packages become no longer visible, and `import mynewname` gives a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I don't want to change the name of the project or structure, just the top level name under which the package is installed. Something like `import mynewname.myproject.package1` would also work, but i'm unsure of how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Should be as simple as renaming the directory `myproject/myproject` to  `myproject/mynewname`.

Comment: I don't want to rename anything in the project which is the tricky part. I just want to create some sort of installation wrapper or something. The issue is in reality the name of myproject is quite generic, and when installing it I want to install it under a more specific name.

Comment: Use `package_dir` then, it will allow you to have different names for the directories in your source and for the actual importable packages (i.e. the directories are renamed during the build). Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141103/11138259 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59662834/11138259 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57853378/11138259

Comment: adding something like :
    `package_dir={ 'mynewname.myproject': 'myproject'}`,
still doesn't work.

Comment: There is something I don't understand. Where is located the `setup.py` in the directory tree? Which of the directories in the directory tree are supposed to be the _top-level modules_?

Comment: updated the question, its located at the top level. `myproject'`is the top-level module, but I either want to install it under a different name or with a wrapper module a level above to give `mynewname.myproject`

Comment: Alright then I guess, you need `package_dir={'mynewname': 'myproject'}`. But I believe you will also have to modify the list for `packages`, since `find_packages` will still return untransformed package names such as `myproject.*`.

Comment: the above approach with transforming the package list works when not in development mode, otherwise in dev mode it still defaults to using the original package name.

Comment: That is true. There is no way around it nowadays as far as I know.

Comment: Is there a solution now, after almost two years?